# How to highlight table row when searching instead of just text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that uses a simple text input to search for a string. If it finds the string, it highlights only the string itself.  All of my data is inside a table, so I'm wondering if it is possible to highlight the entire row if it finds the string anywhere in the row?

This JS Fiddle has a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s8fTA/

This script uses the search string, but calls the highlight script that is below:

```
$(function() {

var search = $('.beer-search'),
    content = $('.beer-list'),
    matches = $(), index = 0;

// Listen for the text input event
search.on('input', function(e) {

    // Only search for strings 2 characters or more
    if (search.val().length >= 2) {

        // Use the highlight plugin
        content.highlight(search.val(), function(found) {
        });
    }
    else {
        content.highlightRestore();
    }

});

});
```

Highlight script:
(function($) {

```
var termPattern;

$.fn.highlight = function(term, callback) {

    return this.each(function() {

        var elem = $(this);

        if (!elem.data('highlight-original')) {

            // Save the original element content
            elem.data('highlight-original', elem.html());

        } else {

            // restore the original content
            elem.highlightRestore();

        }

        termPattern = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', 'ig');

        // Search the element's contents
        walk(elem);

        // Trigger the callback
        callback && callback(elem.find('.match'));

    });
};

$.fn.highlightRestore = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.html(elem.data('highlight-original'));
    });

};

function walk(elem) {

    elem.contents().each(function() {

        if (this.nodeType == 3) { // text node

            if (termPattern.test(this.nodeValue)) {
                $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(termPattern, '<span class="match">$1</span>'));
            }
        } else {
            walk($(this));
        }
    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the row where the text is found:

```
content.highlight(search.val(), function(found) {    
    // like this - first parent to select the column (td) - second parent to select the row (tr)            
    found.parent().parent().css('background','yellow');

    // or like this - finds the closest row (tr) 
    found.closest('tr').css('background','yellow');
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s8fTA/1/)

Comment: one .parent() would suffice.

Comment: Not realy it will just select the column and not the row.

Comment: Instead of .parent(), you might consider .closest('tr').  Then you can be more flexible with your content html.